# Objective-C open links in Safari and Alert Dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIwebView, it has a few links within the webpage. I want a certain link to open an alert modal like in image #1

Also, how can use the code below to make something like this - (IMAGE #1) http://screenshot.it.sftcdn.net/blog/it/2014/01/Block-user-03-Tasto-Block-378x568.png in objective-c

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Open In..."
                 message:@"Which app would you like to open?"
          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *mapsAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Maps"
            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
              if (![self openURLForString:@"maps://"]) {
                  NSLog(@"Couldn't Open Maps");
              }
          }];
    UIAlertAction *youtubeAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YouTube"
            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
              if (![self openURLForString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"]) {
                  NSLog(@"Couldn't Open YouTube");
              }
          }];
    UIAlertAction *messagesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Messages"
            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
              if (![self openURLForString:@"sms://"]) {
                  NSLog(@"Couldn't Open Messages");
              }
          }];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
         handler:nil];

    [alertController addAction:mapsAction];
    [alertController addAction:youtubeAction];
    [alertController addAction:messagesAction];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)openURLForString:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Where the "report inappropriate" being a link opening in a second UIwebView that opens up OVER the parent webview and the "share" opens up in Safari.
(Disregard the "copy link/URL")

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... are you asking how to perform a modal view controller transition to present a new web view?

Comment: @stuart #1) I want a certain link in the webpage of the uiwebview to open an alert modal like in image #1  #2) Where the "report inappropriate" in IMAGE #1 being a link opening in a second UIwebView that opens up OVER the parent webview and the "share" opens up in Safari. (Disregard the "copy link/URL")

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first register your view controller for the web view protocol.

And then in your view controller implement the delegate method for web view did start loading and check the URL being called and do your tasks accordingly using an if else check

Here's the delegate reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/

Answered from my phone. Pardon syntax.

Hope this helps.